# where are the parity log files in daemon mode

Tags: parity, logs, daemon

in parity there is a `daemon` switch witch is useful but I can not find the logs in this mode.

Where does parity write the logs in daemon mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ethcore parity [Issue 1560](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/issues/1560) reported that daemon was not logging and it was fixed in this [commit](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/commit/41ddc30ef5023683672fc5a2b2174cc75f9e3a38)

```
--log-file FILENAME      Specify a filename into which logging should be
                         directed.
```

Use

```
parity daemon --log-file /path/to/parity.log
```

For different logging customizations check [How to make parity write logs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3331/how-to-make-parity-write-logs)